# use post meta in add_meta_boxes action

Tags: metabox, post-meta

Is there any way to use get_post_meta within a function called by the add_meta_boxes action hook?

I only want to display the meta box if a specific post meta matches a regex, but so far, I have not idea how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not put condition in callback function as it will display the meta box without the HTML.
Better you can wrap `add_meta_box()` in `if` condition.

If you are on post edit screen you can get the post id in this way.

```
$post_id = false;
if (!empty($_POST['post_ID'])) {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
} else if (!empty($_GET['post'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
}

if (get_post_meta($post_id, 'yourKey', true)) {
    add_meta_box($id, $title, $callback, $screen, $context, $priority, $callback_args);
}
```

Comment: $_GET['post'] instead global $post worked, thank you.